# How does a free variable affect the attributes of a local variable in R?

Tags: r, lexical-scope

I have a constructor function that creates a function.  There is a variable named 'features' that is local to the constructor, and another variable named 'features' that is local to the function that is created by the constructor.  These are distinguished in the code below as:

1) `## -->  'features' assignment 1 (see question)
      features <- paramIN`

2) `## --> 'features' assignment 2 (see question)
        features[!paramIN] <- p`

Three observations;

1) if I move `features <- paramIN` inside the returned function but ahead of `features[!paramIN] <- p`, the program also works. This makes sense because `paramIN` is a free variable inside the returned function, `features` is local to the returned function, and `features <- paramIN` declares and initializes `features` before it is subset and assigned.

2) if I use `features[!paramIN] <<- p` and keep the first declaration of `features` outside of the returned function, the program also works, and further, the first instance of `features` is updated when the returned function is used.  In this case both `features` and `paramIN` are free variables as far as the returned function is concerned.  It appears that `features` inside the returned function refers to `features` declared outside the returned function. All is good.

HERE IS MY SPECIFIC QUESTION:

3) But If I use `features[!paramIN] <- p` as given, but delete `features <- paramIN` altogether, the program fails because it cannot find `features`. It appears that the first declaration (outside the returned function) is necessary to establish `features` as a two element vector. But the 'inner' `features` is a different variable than the 'outer' `features`; it is local to the returned function, so how can its existence and structure be determined by the declaration of `features` outside the returned function?

```
## make.Function
## ============
## Constructor to make a function that accepts a vector of one or two elements 

## Input argument:
##    
##    paramIN: 2-element vector to initialize and subset'features'
##        There are two instances of 'features':
##          One is local to make.Function(), and the second is local to the function defined inside make.Function()
##
##        Acceptable values for paramIN:
##        paramIn=c(<double>,FALSE):  The constructed function accepts 
##                                    a scalar double and assigns it to 'features[1]'
##        paramIn=c(FALSE,<double>):  The constructed function accepts 
##                                    a scalar double and assigns it to 'features[2]'
##        paramIn=c(FALSE,FALSE):     The constructed function accepts 
##                                    a 2-element vector of doubles and assigns it to 'features' -OR -
##                                    The constructed function accepts
##                                    a scalar double and assigns it to both elements of 'features'

make.Function <- function(paramIN=c(FALSE,FALSE)) {

  ## 'paramIN', and 'features' are local variables in make.Function

  ## -->  'features' assignment 1 (see question)
  features <- paramIN

  ## This function is returned by make.Function
  function(p) {

    ## --> 'features' assignment 2 (see question)
    features[!paramIN] <- p

    x <- features[1]
    y <- features[2]

    ## This is a simple function
    x+2*y
  } 
}
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. Perhaps you could trim the comments and show the code for the three scenarios you define. For Q3, though, it seems if you take out `features <- paramIN` then the very first appearance of `features` would be in `features[!paramIN] <- p` and since the vector `features` doesn't exist anywhere, you'll get an error. This is true anywhere. If you don't have `a` defined, 
`a[c(T,F)]<-1` will throw an error but `a<-c(1,1)` won't.

Comment: @MrFlick: Thank you!  I struggled with how to phrase the question, and I admit it still reads somewhat unclear even to me. But you got the essence of my question anyway. To rephrase: How does the local variable a[c(T,F)] inside the inner function "see" and be defined by the free variable a<-c(T,F) that is outside the inner function?

Comment: A function can search its calling environment for any objects it needs. Once a function finishes, anything not sent to the calling environment (preferably via `return` rather than `<<-` ) is gone, because the function's temporary environment is gone.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Since R uses lexical scoping, did you mean "defining enviroment" instead of "calling environment?" In any case, I think I see what you are getting at. At the time of the `a[c(T,F)]<-1` assignment, the defined function (returned by the constructor) looks at the environment in which it was defined to figure out what `a` is. The `a[c(T,F)]<-1` assignment creates the `a` variable local to the defined function.  Am I getting close?

Comment: I think that's what I meant :-) -- whatever environment the function itself resides in (as an object).